# Admob fill rate dropped to 0% from ~80%

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, admob

Admob fill rate suddenly dropped to 0% from around 80% for one of my mobile games. Other apps are fine.

Average request is 20K.

Ad formats: banner, interstitial, and rewarded video ads.

Location:  all countries.

I contacted Admob support, still waiting for a response.

Is there anything I can do?
I could not find anything useful on the net.

Comment: You can run multiple ad providers. Take a look at this question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/154659/why-would-i-want-to-use-multiple-ad-providers-for-my-mobile-game

Comment: I already use a mediation service, Appodeal. However, the issue is Admob not providing any ads for this game. Other mediated networks work as expected. Admob used work well and provided around 20K ads daily but suddenly stopped. Since Admob usually has higher fill rates, when there is no fill from other networks, no ad is shown.